# How to create hyperlink in pdf file which link to section,named destination,section in another pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink

Create hyperlink in PDF file using c# which link to another PDF files section or named destination. On clicking the link should open any section or named destination in the targeting PDF file.